# how can I select this type(postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is table's column. json type.

| actions |
| --- |
| [{"action_type":"page_engagement","value":"4"},{"action_type":"video_view","value":"7"}] |

I'd like to select this column to convert like this.

| page_engagement | video_view |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 |

Comment: What if the JSON array contains more than two elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON path query to get those two elements and extract the value:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(actions, '$[*] ? (@.action_type == "page_engagement")') ->> 'value' as page_engagement,
       jsonb_path_query_first(actions, '$[*] ? (@.action_type == "video_view")') ->> 'value' as video_view
from the_table
```

This requires `actions` to be defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it isn't, you need to cast the column: `actions::jsonb`

Note that if there are multiple array elements with `page_engagement` or `video_view` only the first ones will be taken.